# R flexdashboard side-bar menu

Tags: html, css, r, twitter-bootstrap, flexdashboard

I was wondering if its possible to recreate a shiny-dashboard like menu in flexdashboard?

I'm using flexdashboard with crosstalk. In the current setting I'm having too many inputs in the sidebar. So basically, I'd like hide them like submenu items in foldable menu items.

Any ideas how I can pull this off? I'm guessing its possible to use external css/bootstrap elements.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try these examples?https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/examples.html